# Merge by distance messes up shading?

Tags: import, normals, geometry, external-applications

I have recently encountered the following problem: I am importing a model from *WOW Model Viewer*, but it is imported in such a way that faces are not connected, so in order to rig and animate it properly, I have to use *Merge by Distance* to prevent "...bone heat weighting ..." Error. However, this messes up the shading for whatever reason.

*Model before merge by distance:*

[image]

*Model after merge by distance:*

[image]

**Q:** How can I get my model shaded as it was originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem wasn't in the "Merge by distance", but rather because after I imported the model all edges were marked as sharp and I cleared them. If I don't clear them everything works fine. So to anyone having the same problem leave the edges marked as sharp.