# Merge Vertices By Distance causes weird shading

Tags: import, lighting, geometry

So I downloaded this Sonic Rush model from https://www.models-resource.com/ds_dsi/sonicrush/model/11250/ and it has some issues.

[image: Sonic's model from Sonic Rush]

None of the vertices are connected, and the head has 4 faces for every face.

[image: Sonic's ear split apart, revealing 4 faces for every side of his pyramid-shaped ear]

So I select the whole model in Edit Mode, go to Vertex> Merge Vertices> By Distance.
That fixed those issues, but now the shadows are all in weird places.
[image: Same model as before, but with weird shading]
I've tried marking the edges as sharp (see [Merge by distance messes up shading?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167282/merge-by-distance-messes-up-shading)) but that only makes it worse.
[image: Even worse shading.]
**Q**: What can I do?